# About cache in PHP

Tags: php, yii2, memcached

I have few question where I am confused about the server side cache in PHP. I am using Yii2 to set MemCache. And my question are:-

1.How can I get expire time of cache variable with id?

```
\Yii::$app->cache->set('cacheId',$counter,$expireTime); //set cache with id cacheId
```

2.If I set same cache id/ overwrite cache id without $expireTime. It will take default expire time or from before?

```
\Yii::$app->cache->set('cacheId',\Yii::$app->cache->get(cacheId)+1); //overwrite cachewith id cacheId.
```

Code looks are in Yii2 but my question is related to server side cache mechanism in PHP.

Thanks You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1.**

Yii2 does not offer a way to retrieve expiration time, see [API Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-cache.html).
MemCache specifically also does not support this if you check the [PHP Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php), so if this information is crucial for your scenario, you have to store it yourself or use a cache implementation which supports it.

**Question 2.**

Yes, if you overwrite a cached item with `set`, a completely new expiration time will be applied, so if none is given, the default will be used.